# gmail plugin to drag and drop mail in to

Tags: javascript, plugins, gmail

I want a gmail plugin (google app script) that allows me to drag an email from the inbox to the plugin card on the right hand side and capture this as an object. I then want to send this on to an external API. This can come later, I hope to be able to work this out.

I have been researching for over a week now and still no clue how to implement this. I am new to google app script / plugins and this is proving harder than I would have expected.

I have been researching for over a week on the google app script developer site. I have made a new plugin from the guide but still none the wiser how it all works. I have a manifest (appscript.json) and GS file. But this is copied from the guide.

I have nothing worth showing. It seems GS is very different from JS. Maybe I'm wrong.

I expect a plugin on the right hand side of gmail inbox (This is standard) where I drag and drop an email in to the plugin card which I expect to treat as a form. At this point I am happy if the object is simply returned, i.e. messageId within the card.

Comment: Unfortunately, gmail add-ons (or plugins as you call them) are restricted to a fixed set of supported widgets([see restrictions](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/guides/restrictions#gmail_add-ons)), none of which allow for drag-n-drop functionality. In addition, a gmail add-on can only access the contents of the currently opened email message. The features you want to build are just not viable with gmail add-ons.

Comment: Thanks Dimu. I just came across the Triggers and see it only works once the email is open or you're composing a message. https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/triggers

Comment: @DimuDesigns I have since discovered gmail app allows to select all mail within the inbox. I have also come across the advanced services / external api which I suspect is using the gmail app script cmds to access all mail. But I find it odd its only limited to the external api.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to trigger a gmail app script / plugin prior to opening a message.
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/triggers

Can I give these points to Dimu Designs?